# Looking for a word that describes the manufacturing date format of 1Qxx

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

At our manufacturing company we frequently use expiration or cure dates in the format of **nQxx**

> Ex1. 2Q18 = second quarter 2018
>
> Ex2. 4Q17 = fourth quarter 2017

I think this date format is common enough to have a name in the manufacturing world but I don't know what the name of this format could be so I can refer to it easily. Nobody seems to know what to call it. Thus, what is a word that describes the manufacturing date format of 1Qxx

Comment: I think the other way around is more common, e.g. (20)18Q2.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you will get will be to describe it as **xQYY** format, analogous to what the SAS reference describes as [**YYQx format**](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p024gsdcagozdnn1se1nqs4rnwjl.htm).

Interestingly, the [ISO 8601 date and time standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) makes no mention of quarters at all.

Comment: That is the other way around, right? The OP asks for xQYY, this is YYQx.

Comment: @JJJ I'm suggesting that the OP describe it as _xQYY_ format, and offered up the SAS _YYQx_ format as an analogy.